# Windows 10 - Computer will not enter reduced power mode

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power

This has been asked before in the form of "Windows X won't sleep", and I've unsuccessfully followed all of the prescribed diagnostic steps everywhere I can find.

Some time, about 2 weeks ago, my desktop computer stopped being able to *start the screensaver, sleep, or turn off the monitors*. This manifests as an always-on 100% bright pair of screens, and it's driving me nuts. I've rebooted the machine several times and run `powercfg -energy` more than I can count looking for possible culprits. Likewise, `powercfg /requests` is generally empty. There's nothing readily identifiable as the problem. If I manually put the computer to sleep, it will generally (but not always) stay that way.

Can anyone suggest additional steps?

```
C:\>powercfg /requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.
```

Report from `powercfg -energy`: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fajk78zm/embedded/result/

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "reduced power mode"? Looking at your report your current plan is "High Performance - Maximizes screen brightness and might increase PC performance. This plan uses a lot more energy". Why aren't you using "Power Saver - Saves power by reducing PC performance and screen brightness" - which is a reduced power mode?

Comment: Specifically, my plan is set to turn on the screen savers after some minutes and turn off the monitors after some more, but neither ever occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue turned out to be the PS4 controller I had connected via USB. Evidently, when the PS4 controller is connected, or InputMapper is running (software to enhance PS4 usability), Windows 10 will not sleep.